# Global list in C/gtk+

Tags: c, list, gtk

I need in global list in my gtk+ application, i use for it GList:

For example:

I have structure:

```
typedef struct _data
{
  Glist list;
}Data;
```

I want to use one copy of the list in the whole program:

I have a function bulid my list:

```
gboolean build_list()
{
   Data->list = g_list_append(Data->list, "First ");
   Data->list = g_list_append(Data->list, "Second ");
   Data->list = g_list_append(Data->list, "Third ");

   g_list_foreach(Data->list, (GFunc)printf, NULL);
}
```

After calling this function to display all items from the list:

**First Second Third**

,but when i try to make it in another function - for example:

```
void foreach()
{   
    g_list_foreach(Data->list, (GFunc)printf, NULL);
}
```

I see error in gdb:

**Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0xb7335700 (LWP 5364)]
0xb765a7d7 in strchrnul () from /lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
**

How can i create global list in my application?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typedef struct _data
{
  Glist list;
} Data;
```

That makes `Data` a type (i.e. you can define a variable of type `Data` by doing `Data data_var;), but in your code you are using it as a variable:

```
gboolean build_list()
{
   Data->list = g_list_append(Data->list, "First ");
```

If you want to use it is a variable, you need to change things to:

```
struct _data
{
  Glist list;
} Data;
```

When you do that, `Data` is not a pointer, so you would access it's data like this (notice that you're using `.` instead of `->`):

gboolean build_list()
    {
       Data.list = g_list_append(Data.list, "First ");